# 'react-query' - useMutation fire onSuccess while should fire OnError

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I have issue with error response from axios client to my useMutation.

axios client

```
import axios from "axios";

const client = axios.create({ baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}/${process.env.REACT_APP_API_PREFIX}` });

export const request = ({...options}) => {
    client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDetails')).idToken}`
    client.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    const onSuccess = (response) => {
        console.log('AXIOS !!!!! request Successful!!!', response.config.url)
        return response;
    };

    const onError = error => {
        console.error('AXIOS !!!!!  Request Failed:', error.config.url);
        return error
    };

    return client(options).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
}
```

this is my useMutatuon file

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import {request} from '../utils/axios';

const useAddInvestmentAction = (investment)  => {
    // Define the headers object
    return request({ 
        url: '/investments/investment1', 
        method: 'post', 
        data: investment,
    })
}


export const useAddInvestmentData = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    return useMutation(useAddInvestmentAction,{
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries('InvestmentsData')
            console.log('Investment Added Successfully!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log('Investment Failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}

export default useAddInvestmentData;
```

when I change my url to not exist uri my onSuccess trigger and not my onError. The Axios print onError

any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw an error from the `catch` block. Also, remember that the `catch` block like `then` returns a promise unless an error is thrown.

```
    const onError = error => {
        console.error('AXIOS !!!!!  Request Failed:', error.config.url);
        throw new Error('error_mesage') // <- this is the change
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `request` method you first catch the error and then you are returning the response of the error, not the error. Due to this the request is marked as successful. You will have to throw the error in order to forward the error.

In `onError` you can throw a new Error

```
export const request = ({...options}) => {
    client.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDetails')).idToken}`
    client.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    const onSuccess = (response) => {
        console.log('AXIOS !!!!! request Successful!!!', response.config.url)
        return response;
    };

    const onError = error => {
        console.error('AXIOS !!!!!  Request Failed:', error.config.url);
        throw new Error(error)
    };

    return client(options).then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
}
```

Also few suggestions:

1. `useAddInvestmentAction`: This isn't a hook. Just a method to add investment action. Just name it something like addInvestmentAction
2. `request`: This method waits for a response using `then`. Better to make this method async.
3. Better to use [interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) for implementing onSuccess and onError